# SSRS Dynamic columns with collapsed rows

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I have an SSRS report that outputs like this:

[image: My output]

My source query is:

```
SELECT  '2015-09-01 00:45:00.000' AS QuarterStart,'SMITH' AS EMPLOYEE_1
UNION
SELECT  '2015-09-01 01:00:00.000','SMITH'
UNION
SELECT  '2015-09-01 01:15:00.000','SMITH' 
UNION
SELECT  '2015-09-02 00:45:00.000','SMITH'
UNION
SELECT  '2015-09-02 01:00:00.000','SMITH'
UNION
SELECT  '2015-09-02 01:15:00.000','SMITH'
```

But I want there to only be three rows in the output with Tuesday and Wednesday both populated instead of six rows with three blank spaces on each day. How do I get my table matrix to "collapse" these rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the **column grouping** on the matrix.

[image]

Right click on the column head and go to Column Group then Group Properties.

[image]